# Erro ao tentar abrir mapa com localização desativada

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

Até agora, o objetivo desse aplicativo é, ao abrir, localizar o usuário e exibir alguns pontos já mapeados. Quando o app abre (localização desativada ou não), ele pergunta se o usuário permite que ele use sua localização. Ele vai em permissões, ativa o local e, até aí, OK.

O problema é que eu quero que, quando a localização do dispositivo esteja desativada, ele avise que precisa dela ligada e que peça pro usuário ativar.

Desenvolvi o código abaixo e testei. O aplicativo roda normal com a localização ativada, mas quando desativo, ele para de funcionar e a mensagem de erro aparece:

> "O aplicativo X parou de funcionar".

Já tentei criar um método `onCheck` (usei a resposta [dessa pergunta aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25175522/how-to-enable-location-access-programmatically-in-android)), também, mas ele retorna a mensagem para ativar o GPS mesmo que ele esteja ligado. Parece que a condição não funciona. Alguém pode dar uma analisada e ver no que estou errando?

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private static final String FINE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
    private static final String COARSE_LOCATION = Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION;
    private static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    private Boolean mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationProviderClient;
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (mLocationPermissionsGranted) {
            getDeviceLocation();
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }

            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }

        float zoomLevel = 25.0f;

    //meus pontos mapeados aqui 
    }

    private BitmapDescriptor BitmapDescriptorfromVector(MapsActivity mapsActivity, int marker) {
        Drawable vectorDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(mapsActivity, marker);
        vectorDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), vectorDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
        return BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    private void moveCamera(LatLng latLng, float zoom) {
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, zoom));
    }

    private void getDeviceLocation() {
        mFusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        try {
            if (mLocationPermissionsGranted) {
                final Task location = mFusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation();
                location.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Location currentLocation = (Location) task.getResult();
                            moveCamera(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()),
                                    15);
                        } else {
                            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
                            alertDialog.setMessage("A localização deste dispositivo parece estar desativada. Deseja ativar?");
                            alertDialog.setPositiveButton("SIM", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });
                            alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NÃO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                            alertDialog.show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } catch (SecurityException e) {

        }
    }

    private void getLocationPermission() {
        String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION};

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(), FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(), COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
                initMap();
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        permissions,
                        LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    permissions,
                    LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;

        switch (requestCode) {
            case LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
                        if (grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                            mLocationPermissionsGranted = false;
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    mLocationPermissionsGranted = true;
                    initMap();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void initMap() {
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        getLocationPermission();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para pedir para que o usuário ligue o gps caso desligado faça:

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        //Pede para ligar o gps caso desligado
        String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);

        if (provider == null || provider.length() == 0) {
            GpsDialog();
        }
    }

private void GpsDialog() {
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener dialogClickListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                switch (which) {
                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
                        Intent callGPSSettingIntent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(callGPSSettingIntent);
                        break;

                    case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
                        finish();
                        break;
                }
            }

        };

        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog mNoGpsDialog = builder.setMessage("Por favor, ative seu GPS para continuar.")
                .setPositiveButton("Ativar", dialogClickListener).setNegativeButton("Cancelar", dialogClickListener)
                .create();
        mNoGpsDialog.show();

    }
```

E pq o `onResume()` ao invés de `onCreate()`?
Simples, caso o usuário minimize o app e o abra dnv, caso o gps esteja desligado, ele pede novamente.

Como você disse que seu app fecha caso o gps não esteja ativado, no `onResume()`, você coloca um `else` no meu `if`, este irá chamar os métodos que preparam e montam o mapa, assim você terá certeza que só carregou tudo após o gps está ligado